# Garbage collector won't collect an object created with using

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I want to test for object references held improperly and wrote a test that always failed. I simplified the test to the following behaviour:

```
    [Test]
    public void ScopesAreNotLeaking()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef;
        Stub scope = null;
        using (scope = new Stub())
        {
            weakRef = new WeakReference(scope);
        }
        scope = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Assert.That(weakRef.Target, Is.Null);
    }
```

This test however, which does the same without using, passes:

```
    [Test]
    public void ScopesAreNotLeaking()
    {
        WeakReference weakRef;
        Stub scope = new Stub();
        weakRef = new WeakReference(scope);
        scope = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Assert.That(weakRef.Target, Is.Null);
    }
```

The used stub class is simple enough:

```
class Stub : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()  {}
}
```

Can someone please explain me that behaviour or - even better - has an idea how to make sure that the object gets garbage collected?

PS: Bear with me if a similar question was asked before. I only examined those questions that have **using** in the title.

Comment: Why would you want to test this? Garbage Collection normally only takes place when necessary calling GC.Collect is (in most cases) making your program slower rather than faster.

Comment: I suspect there may be a local introduced by the using statement. Use ildasm to see if all the references in the function to the object are truly cleared before the call to GC.Collect. Also try to put the using bit in a separate function that returns the weak reference.

Comment: The class Stub is simplified. The original object is a Scope-like flyweight that is referenced by many other objects. By the time it is disposed, it must be dereferenced by all other objects or the application will likely blow up within hours.

Comment: GC is not deterministic, it makes no sense to guess why it works sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: @Sven: You have a hit here: Putting the using statement in a separate method makes the test pass. Now, if you write an answer, I can mark it as such...

Comment: Thanks, I copy/pasted my comment into an answer. :)

Comment: Though only a few objects will be created per web request, they hold references to a lot of other objects, that won't be GC'ed due to this. The Scope-objects are temporarily saved by a singleton manager. If they are not released from the manager object, the heap will grow above a given limit.

Comment: Allthough I don't know your specific application or the design behind the application I would say you're referencing way too much objects if this is really going to be a problem.

Comment: @MZywitza: Why won't they be GC'd because of this? The weak reference is not stopping stub from being GC'd (unless there is a massive bug in the MS implmentation), it just isn't being GC'd when you expect it to be... When the GC comes to look at stub, it will see the weak reference clear it before destructing the stub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there may be a local introduced by the using statement. Use ildasm to see if all the references in the function to the object are truly cleared before the call to `GC.Collect`. Also try to put the using bit in a separate function that returns the weak reference.

Comment: using() is not generating additional locals that are still in scope outside the using statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: They are not in scope for the C# code; but from the point of view of MSIL all locals remain in existence until the end of the function, so if they are not nulled out the GC won't collect the object.

Comment: A few of us have had a closer look at the IL and it does indeed appear that this is correct. Another local variable is created in the *using* case (so you actually end up with two references to stub), of which only one is released.

Answer (score 5):

using is not designed to force garbage collection but to ensure dispose is called. Dispose allows you to release non-garbage collected resources like file handles. Garbage collection happens when c# is good and ready.

Comment: @codymanix: just being facetious, I simply meant GC timing is non-deterministic

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is "given that in the second example, without the *using*, the stub is collected after the GC.Collect call, why isn't it in the first case"? Why does the use of *using* have any effect? (which it does appear to, repeatably, having run the code)

Comment: @Rob Levine: you'd have to have a full understanding of the GC to understand why an object is collected or not. The important point, to me, is that GC is non-deterministic so you cannot rely on the second test to pass. It works with the version of the framework used by the OP now but may fail with a different version or even in a different program.

Comment: I think the OP's question (or certainly mine when I read it) is more a case of "it seems like the *using* is causing the object to be ineligible for garbage collection, like there is hidden strong reference to it". I'm not sure about your deterministic point tho. The behaviour of the GC is deterministic for a given GC isn't it? (e.g. what it does when a gen3 GC occurs). It is non-deterministic in that you don't know when it may chose to collect and what generation but in this case it has been *forced*. I may be wrong on that, but in any case, the curiosity discovered by the OP still stands.

Answer (score 1):

The mark & sweep GC, like it is used in .NET, is not deterministic. 
Even if called by `GC.Collect()` there is no guarantee that is really runs.

Additionally, the using-clause does not have anything to do with garbage collection. If just calls Dispose() on its target object.

Comment: Can you enlarge on this?  Although it's not deterministic, I'm sure the developers who wrote it could tell you what the algorithm is for deciding when it's going to collect.  I would be interested to know :p.

Comment: "Additionally, the using-clause does not have anything to do with garbage collection. If just calls Dispose() on its target object." - that's is the OPs point. WHY does *using* have this effect on the GC. If you run the OPs code you will see the behaviour described is what happens - the question being asked is why.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the result is different on multiple runs or if your change from debug to release config. Using() is creating a finally-clause, who knows how this impacts local variables

Answer (score 1):

Your two test cases are not identical. At the end of a `using` statement, the resource's `Dispose` method is called, it is not set to null. Calling Dispose does not necessarily call the destructor.

Comment: In .net there is such thing like a constructor. Btw. in both examples, scope is set to null.

Comment: Since when? I didn't mention constructors, but C# has both constructors (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) and destructors (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)